# Swift NSDateFormatter not using correct locale and format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is my code:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let usDateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
usDateFormat.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("d MMMM y", options: 0, locale: NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US"))
cmt.date = usDateFormat.stringFromDate(currentDate)
```

I was expecting to get "15 October 2015", but I got "oktober 15, 2015". The month is in swedish locale.

What have I done wrong? Both locale and format are wrong.

Comment: i tried the same code and i am getting this output October 15, 2015

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
let dateString = "2015-10-15"
let formater = NSDateFormatter()
formater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print(dateString)

formater.locale =  NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = formater.dateFromString(dateString)
print(date)
```

**Swift 3 Xcode 8**

```
let dateString = "2015-10-15"
let formater = DateFormatter()
formater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print(dateString)

formater.locale =  Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = formater.date(from: dateString)
print(date!)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What's the difference between doing local en_US_POSIX vs en-US?? The answer above seems to be doing it another way

Answer (score 16):

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:) of `dateFormatFromTemplate`. It states that :

> Return Value
>
> A localized date format string representing the date
>   format components given in template, arranged appropriately for the
>   locale specified by locale.
>
> The returned string may not contain exactly those components given in
>   template, but may—for example—have locale-specific adjustments
>   applied.

So thats the problem about arranging and language. To get the date you are looking for you need to set date formatter's `dateFormat` and `locale` as follow:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let usDateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
usDateFormat.dateFormat = "d MMMM y"
usDateFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
cmt.date = usDateFormat.stringFromDate(currentDate)
```

Comment: Probably a typo :-). LocaleIdentifier is with an underscore, "en_US".

Answer (score 6):

Better Swift 3/3.1 solution:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
let locale1:Locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale
var date =  Date().description(with: locale1)
print(date)
```

//Monday, April 3, 2017...

Comment: Any solution for the current system locale without having to specify en_US?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Date extension in Swift5:

```
extension Date {
    var timestamp: String {
        let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
        return String(format: "%@", dataFormatter.string(from: self))
    }
}
```

You can get the timestamp by

```
print("Now: \(Date().timestamp)")
```

Answer (score -1):

Date Locale:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first ?? "en")
```